# Display the area in common between two surfaces

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, surface, matplotlib-3d

I have the following code, that generates a paraboloid and delivers the part of the area above a lower limit, or below an upper limit, as shown here
[image]

Those results are obtained with the following python code

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r: float = 1.5
    r_min: float = 0.5 * r
    r_max: float = 0.75 * r
    n_points: int = 100

    r: np.ndarray = np.linspace(0, r, n_points)
    r_pellet: np.ndarray = np.linspace(r_min, r_max, n_points)
    theta: np.ndarray = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n_points)
    R, THETA = np.meshgrid(r, theta)

    # Deal with figures
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(projection = "3d")

    # Create projectile surface
    X, Y = R * np.cos(THETA), R * np.sin(THETA)
    Z = (X**2 + Y**2)
    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap="cool", linewidth=0, antialiased=True)

    # Create pellet surface
    # Above lower limit
    X_SUP = np.where(r_min <= X**2 + Y**2, X, np.NAN)
    Y_SUP = np.where(r_min <= X**2 + Y**2, Y, np.NAN)
    Z_SUP = X_SUP**2 + Y_SUP**2

    # Under upper limit
    X_INF = np.where(X**2 + Y**2 <= r_max, X, np.NAN)
    Y_INF = np.where(X**2 + Y**2 <= r_max, Y, np.NAN)
    Z_INF = X_INF**2 + Y_INF**2

    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z_INF, cmap="hot", linewidth=0, antialiased=True)

    ax.set_xlabel("X")
    ax.set_ylabel("Y")
    ax.set_zlabel("Z")

    plt.show()
```

I would like the code to plot the area in common between those two separate plots.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same method to get the requested area, requiring that both conditions be met:

```
    X_INF_SUP = np.where((X**2 + Y**2 >= r_min) & (X**2 + Y**2 <= r_max), X, np.NAN)
    Y_INF_SUP = np.where((X**2 + Y**2 >= r_min) & (X**2 + Y**2 <= r_max), Y, np.NAN)
    Z_INF_SUP = X_INF_SUP**2 + Y_INF_SUP**2
```